# Nodejs: Promise.all no call any of my async method

Tags: node.js, multithreading, promise

I am very confuse about promise.all, I have  a bunch of method like this:

```
const push = async () => {
    for (var i = 0; i < 2000; i++) {
        return new Promise(invoke => {
            client.publish(topic, message, pushOptions); // is mqtt client
            invoke(true);
        });
    }
};
const example2 = async () => {
    console.log('example2 started');
    await push();
    await push();
    await push();
    await push();
    await push();
};  ....
```

Now I want to run all methods by promise all:

```
var syncList = [];
syncList.push(
    example2, example3, example4);
           Promise.all(syncList)
                .then((result) => {
                    console.log(result);
                }).catch(err => {
                    console.log(err);
                });
```

But none of methods start and i got this log on terminal :

```
[ [AsyncFunction: example2], 
  [AsyncFunction: example3], 
  [AsyncFunction: example4] ]
```

Why my method is not running?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is, that you immediately `return` your **first** Promise. Your `push` function is returning only one Promise.

In the following example we have a function that is returning an Array of unresolved Promises. They can be awaited with `Promise.all()`

```
const getPromiseArray = () => {
  console.log('start collecting tasks');
  const allPromises = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    const newTask = new Promise(function(invoke) {
      const taskNr = i;
      setTimeout(() => { // some long operation
        console.log("task " + taskNr);
        invoke();
      }, 400);
    });
    allPromises.push(newTask);
  }

  console.log('end collecting tasks\n');
  return allPromises;
};


(async () => {
  const promisesArray = getPromiseArray();
  await Promise.all(promisesArray);
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Promise.all` get an array of `Promise`s but what you pass to it are not `Promise`s but some async function declaration.
you should run these functions when you pass them to `Promise.all`.

somethings equivalent to this:

```
Promise.all([example2(), example3(), example4()])
```

Of course your `push` functions also seems to be wrong! its loop run just for `i=0` because it returns before the loop iterates for other `i` values.